# Are we unable to use Magento while reindexing Product Flat Data or any other index?

Tags: magento-1.6

I am trying to reindex product flat data(about 85K products) with the following command and I am doing it at night when nobody is using the website and nothing else is going on the server.

```
nohup php -f indexer.php -- -reindex catalog_product_flat &
```

Then I was wondering if we can use the website or work in the backend when reindexing and I could not find any information about that online. So when I was reindexing, I was unable to use website or save product at all. The pages keep loading or show internal server error after a long time. Sometimes it rarely loaded with few pages successfully.

Is it possible to reindex and use our Magento website same time?
Do we just need a higher configuration server in order to keep doing both?

Currently the site is hosted on 8GB RAM and 4 Cores VPS.

Comment: In all liklihood, the indexing process is locking tables, and therefore you can't access the site.

Comment: In that case, we should come up with "site under maintenance" flag so that site down does not scare people. We decided to try another extension that can reindex efficiently in the background. It's still good to know if we need to reindex everything again from shell in same way at some points.

Comment: There are several AJAX extensions that would probably be well suited here.

Answer (score 2):

We had issues with re-indexing on a site with only 15k of products. We had deadlocks and timeouts. We went the same route, running cronjobs late in the night to re-index the database, but if one of the jobs didnt complete, we either left it for the next night, or run the reindex during the day. Not ideal...

So perhaps a couple of questions.

Why do you need to run re-indexing each night?. Are products changing every day that require re-indexing so often.

Have you considered splitting the server up, or perhaps running something like varnish?. Are you using some sort of caching system. This would reduce load on database server directly.

brendan

Comment: We are not doing reindexing every night and we are doing when it is required and 1-3k products are changing everyday. We found an extension that can take care of the reindexing efficiently which is now our current step to implement and then we planned to use varnish. But the question is if we come across magento reindexing again then it is good to know if site down is inevitable although we have server resources. Then we can show site under maintenance but definitely we always want to avoid taking our site down.